# Error page white pdflib and zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf-generation, pdflib

I installed pdflib and I created a controller named generpdf and in action I copy this code

```
try {
$p = new PDFlib();

# This means we must check return values of load_font() etc.
$p->set_option("errorpolicy=return");

/* Enable the following line if you experience crashes on OS X
 * (see PDFlib-in-PHP-HowTo.pdf for details):
 * $p->set_option("usehostfonts=false");
 */

/* all strings are expected as utf8 */
$p->set_option("stringformat=utf8");

/*  open new PDF file; insert a file name to create the PDF on disk */
if ($p->begin_document("", "") == 0) {
die("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
}

$p->set_info("Creator", "hello.php");
$p->set_info("Author", "Rainer Schaaf");
$p->set_info("Title", "Hello world (PHP)!");

$p->begin_page_ext(595, 842, "");

$font = $p->load_font("Helvetica-Bold", "unicode", "");
if ($font == 0) {
die("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
}

$p->setfont($font, 24.0);
$p->set_text_pos(50, 700);
$p->show("Hello world!");
$p->continue_text("(says PHP)");
$p->end_page_ext("");

$p->end_document("");

$buf = $p->get_buffer();
$len = strlen($buf);

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: $len");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=hello.pdf");
    print $buf;

}
catch (PDFlibException $e) {
    die("PDFlib exception occurred in hello sample:\n" .
    "[" . $e->get_errnum() . "] " . $e->get_apiname() . ": " .
    $e->get_errmsg() . "\n");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}

$p = 0;`
```

But I have the page white and error. What can I do so I have not to create any other function. I want just to test the pdflib with framework zend.

Comment: Blank white page just means you have display errors turned off. Check your web server error log to see the error message.

Comment: thanks it's ok i see this message

Comment: so i want to add rectangulaire small coched with out use the formfield thanks in advance